# assigning value to dynamically generated gridview cell in vb.net windows form

Tags: vb.net, gridview

i am trying to assign value from dataset to dynamically generated gridview textbox column,but value is   not visible in the cell but it has been assigned.please help me out.

```
Dim i, j As Integer
     For i = 0 To ds.Tables(4).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To grdincomes.Rows.Count - 1
             If ds.Tables(4).Rows(i)("Income_Head").ToString.Trim = grdincomes.Rows(j).Cells("Income_Head").Value Then
                            grdincomes.Rows(j).Cells("txtamtpay").Value = ds.Tables(4).Rows(i)("amountpaid").ToString.Trim
                            grdincomes.Rows(j).Cells("cmbinctype").Value = ds.Tables(4).Rows(i)("paymentmode").ToString.Trim
                            'MessageBox.Show(grdincomes.Rows(j).Cells("txtamtpay").Value)
                            'MessageBox.Show(grdincomes.Rows(j).Cells("cmbinctype").Value)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            End If
```

Comment: try `grdincomes.Rows(j).Cells("txtamtpay").text= ds.Tables(4).Rows(i)("amountpaid").ToString.Trim`

Comment: it won't work as .text is not member of datagridview cell

Comment: why cant u just use `grdincomes.Rows(j).Columns("txtamtpay").text= ds.Tables(4).Rows(i)("amountpaid").ToString.Trim` or use the columns number instead of name.

Comment: It didn't work,it's throwing an error 'Columns' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'.

Comment: ok now i have checked the same.use column index instead of column name.sure it will work.ie `grdincomes.Rows(j).Cells(0).value= ds.Tables(4).Rows(i)("amountpaid").ToString.Trim`

Comment: first i have bind the grid from dataset and later i am adding two columns dynamically

Comment: i tried with column index too but it didn't work. This is how i am adding column
Dim pos1 As Integer = grdincomes.Columns.Count
                Dim txt As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                With txt
                    .HeaderText = "Amount To Be Paid"
                    .Name = "txtamtpay"
                    .Width = 140
                End With
                grdincomes.Columns.Insert(pos1, txt)